# what is php while loop for executing this sql query

Tags: php, sql

[image]

I'm trying with while loop, unable to find logic or sql query.
I want to print this table like this

---

**Architude** - Sancturay, Park Avenue, Eden Garden, Equniox.

**Che** -Equniox, Eden Garden.

**Kir**- Eden Garden, Allura, MOVO

---

I have tried while loop in PHP and used firsl uid and last uid for logic
I'm not getting it

using this SQL queries

```
SELECT * FROM userprojects ORDER BYuIDASC LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM userprojects ORDER BY uID ASC LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM userprojects ORDER BY uID DESC LIMIT 1
```

```
    <?php 

$countN = '';$countID='0';
while($rowUP = mysqli_fetch_array($resultUP)) { 
if ($countID!=$rowUP['uIDname']) {echo "<p><strong> ".$rowUP['uIDname']." </strong>".$countN." <br>";}
$countN.=$rowUP['pName'];
$countID=$rowUP['uIDname'];
} ?>
```

Comment: sorry for the bad format question, stackoverflow didn't allow me to post properly. asking so many stuffs.

Comment: "didn't allow me to post properly"...means what exactly? You can [edit] your question if you need to change it, and there is guidance on using the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) if you need help with presentation. If you got an error message, it's probably prompting you to adjust the content in some useful way

Comment: Anyway, if you mean `while($rowUP = mysqli_fetch_array($resultUP))`, its purpose is to make sure all the rows are fetched from the result set, because - as per the PHP manual - `mysqli_fetch_array` fetches a single row from the results each time it runs.

Comment: You know php sql, can you solve this query how to print that sql table data into php like that

Comment: To simply loop and echo all the fields, `while($rowUP = mysqli_fetch_array($resultUP)) {
    foreach ($rowUP as $field) echo $field." "; echo "<br/>";
} ` should get you started. You can find plenty of examples of this online already though, there are dozens of tutorials, and examples in the PHP documentation, old SO questions etc. It's not exactly a big secret!

Comment: **How** do you use the query? The code you've shared does not show what `$resultUP_F` or the other two variables contain

Comment: If you're specifically looking for how to group the results like the example you've shown though, then you'd be better with a different SQL query, probably involving GROUP_CONCAT (you can google for examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Query:

```
SELECT `uID`, `uIDname`, `pID`, `pName`, GROUP_CONCAT(`pName`) as `pNameS` FROM userprojects group by uID;
```

and PHP

```
 while($rowUP = mysqli_fetch_array($resultUP)) 
{ 
    echo "<p><strong> ".$rowUP['uIDname']." </strong>".$rowUP['pNameS']." <br>";
}
```

thats simple Instead of -ve marking thay can give answers

output

**Architude** Sanctuary,Park Avenue,Eden Garden,Equniox

**Che** Equniox,Eden Garden

**Kir** Eden Garden,Allura,MOVO

using GROUP_CONCAT, ThanksADyson

Comment: Does this already resolve your problem? Then please add some more explanation, such that others can learn from it. If this should be an edit for the initial question, please **edit the initial question** instead

Comment: Its just how to use GROUP_CONCAT in my problem you can see from sql table image and bottom output